# Can I turn my own Google Play account into a test account without any problems?

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I'm developing our first app that uses in app purchases, and need to test that it's working correctly.

Currently if I try to make a purchase on the "android.test.purchased" item, I get an error message back saying "invalidClient". I'm led to believe that this is because my account is not a test user.

I found this page:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup

which tells me how to set up a test user. I could set up a new user account, but I only have the one Android device to hand, which means doing a factory reset to make this the primary account, and I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Alternatively, can I make my own personal account double up as a test user?
The link above says that test users have limitations, one of which is:

> Test accounts can only be used to purchase items that are listed (and
>   published) in an application's product list.

That seems to imply that I could only use my account to buy things in my in-development apps, and not from other apps as normal.

So can I turn my own personal account into a test user, without any problems when using the account to purchase other apps as normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't affect your abilities to use the test account as a normal account for other apps on  Google Play.

So simply you can use your own account as a test account. (Actually if your account is the publisher account, you don't need to add it as a test account.)

The limitations mentioned in the documentation is a comparison to the publisher account.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way around it. If you just have one device you have to wipe the device and then first sign in with the email address that you want to use as a test account. Only then will you be able to test in-app billing. You can also download other items from the Google Play store. I've done this without any problems.